# Not getting BOUNDARY from the header while using postman to upload a file in asp.net core

Tags: c#, http, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send a file using postman to upload it on a webservice using asp.net core.

[image]

[image]

Now, the generated snippet from postman looks like this after the request

[image]

and in my controller method

request.ContentType.Value is null

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the content-type header you added manually and instead select form-data in POST request > Body